# Cancel previous inner Observables when a new higher-order Observable is emitted

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Consider the following code:

```js
this.msgService.getUserChatList()
    .do( (list) => { 
      this.unread = false;
      console.log(list);
     } )
    .mergeMap( chats => Observable.from(chats) )
    .mergeMap( chat => this.msgService.getLastMessage(chat['id']).map( lastMessage => this.containsUnreadMessages(lastMessage, chat['lastPresence']) ) )
    .filter( state => state === true )
    .subscribe( (unread) => {
      this.unread = true;
      console.log('result ', res);
    } );
```

getUserChatList():
 - emits an element each time one of the chat changes
 - an element is a raw array containing all chats meta-data
 - never completes

getLastMessage():
 - is an Observable that never completes

In the second mergeMap I am calling the function getLastMessage().
I need to be observe this observable **only until** a new item is emitted by the getUserChatList() otherwise I would multiple observations on last message of the same chat.

Illustration :

1. `getUserChatList` emits : [chatMetaA:{}, chatMetaB:{}]
2. code go through `getLastMessage` and start to observe lastMessage of chatA and chatB
3. one of the chat change so a new item is emitted by `getUserChatList` containing the new version of the meta-data of the chats: [chatMetaA:{}, chatMetaB:{}]
4. code go through `getLastMessage` and start to observe lastMessage of chatA and chatB. So we now observe twice last message of chatA and chatB

And it will go on and on...

My question is, **how could I cancel observation on getLastMessage() once a new item is emitted by getUserChatList()**? I tried using switch but couldn't manage to make it work

Comment: Use the `switchMap` operator

Comment: @martin if I use it instead of the first mergeMap then nothing change (my problem still occurs) and if I use it instead of the second mergeMap then my code is executed only for the last item of my array which is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was indeed to use switchMap:

```
this.msgService.getUserChatList()
    .do( () => { this.unread = false } )
    .switchMap(
      chats => Observable.from(chats)
        .mergeMap( chat => this.msgService.getLastMessage(chat['id'])
        .map( lastMessage => this.containsUnreadMessages(lastMessage, chat['lastPresence']) ) )
    )
    .filter( state => state === true )
    .subscribe( (unread) => {
      this.unread = true;
      console.log('result ', res);
    } );
```